# How to show Lat and Long using phonegap

Tags: cordova, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to show (on alert) a position of GPS using Phonegap when I call other function, but it doesn't work at all.

My code:

```
var lat=0.0;
var lon=0.0;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
function onSuccess(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
}

function ShowPosition(){
 alert("Latitude: "+lat+" longitude: "+lon);
}
```

EDIT: The showPosition function is called on "onclick" event on a button of my HTML code

Comment: showPosition is never called and `lat` and `long` aren't available in scope of ShowPosition.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault. ShowPosition is called on "onclick" event on button of HTML code. Why lat and lon aren't available on ShowPosition? They are global variable.

Comment: ok, sorry i missed that. maybe you should do this all after clicking a button instead of after loading the page

Comment: I tried before and alert only show Latitude: 0 longitude: 0

Comment: Is the onSuccess function called?

Comment: I try again to put function that get position on button instead of after loading page and it works!, TY mr.VVoo!

Answer (score 1):

you have to call ShowPosition() function somewhere, in your code you never called this function.
 that's the issue, your code is perfect.

hope this may help you.
thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault. ShowPosition is called on "onclick" event on button of HTML code.

Comment: can you get lat and long in onSuccess function ?